# With Algolia search, 504 Gateway TimeOut

Tags: wordpress, algolia

I installed the plugin Search from Algolia on my Wordpress web site. Currently, the search bar is visible, you can write your search on it and it gives results. But I have a problem : when I click on a result (which is an article of the web site), I can't reach the article, the "504 Gateway TimeOut" page appears. Do you know what is the problem ?

I'm a novice in web development and I apologize for my English.

Comment: In general, 504 status code has to do with your infra setup.
Do you experience the same when turning off the plugin?
What is the shape of the URL when following the result? Is it the same than the URL your website is hosted on?

Comment: You were right, it was a problem in the URL ! Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

If you can write your search and get the results that means Algolia is working properly.

You can get more information about the search you're performing by opening the dev tools of your browser and going to the "Network" tab.

In the network tab you can also check the request that is giving a 504 error. Verify that the requested URL is the one you're expecting.

Try to understand the HTTP errors like the one you're getting (504) so that it will be easier in the future to understand what's not working.

Learn more about the devtools:

- Chrome: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/
- Firefox: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Web_Console/Opening_the_Web_Console

Learn more about HTTP codes: 
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes

Comment: As you said, it was a problem in the URL. Thank you for the documentation !